# using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE insert query for update already exist row

Tags: c#, mysql

```
connection()
{
  OleDbConnection nwindConn=new OleDbConnection();
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection con= new MySqlConnection();
  MySqlCommand cmd;
  con.ConnectionString ="server=localhost;" +
                        "uid=root;"+
                        "pwd=;" +
                        "database=globasys;" ;
  DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;       
  string select = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM categories";
  MySqlDataAdapter catDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(select, con);
  string insert = "insert into categories(CategoryID,CategoryName)
      VALUES(@CategoryID,@CategoryName)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CategoryID=@CategoryID";
  catDA.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(insert, con);
  catDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", MySqlDbType.Int32
                                     , 11, "CategoryID");
  catDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CategoryName", MySqlDbType.VarChar
                                     , 250, "CategoryName");            
  DataSet catDS = new DataSet();
  catDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
  catDA.Fill(catDS, "Categories");
  DataSet newdt = new DataSet();
  newdt = getnewdata();        
  int i= catDA.Update(newdt, "Categories");
}

public DataSet getnewdata()
{
  DataSet catDS=new DataSet();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("CategoryID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add(col1);            
  DataColumn col=new DataColumn("CategoryName",typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add(col);          
  DataColumn[] Cols = { dt.Columns[0] };
  dt.PrimaryKey =Cols;
  DataRow crow = dt.NewRow();
  crow["CategoryID"]=1;
  crow["CategoryName"]="io";
  dt.Rows.Add(crow);
  dt.TableName = "Categories";            
  DataRow crow1 = dt.NewRow();
  crow1["CategoryID"] = 3;
  crow1["CategoryName"] = "p";
  dt.Rows.Add(crow1);
  dt.TableName = "Categories";
  catDS.Tables.Add(dt);
  return catDS;
}
```

I want the insert command `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update the old values with the new values. If the values does not exist then it needs to insert a new value.

It does execute, but it does not update the existing value

considering my table

```
1 a
2 b
```

Using this query

```
INSERT INTO categories(CategoryID,CategoryName) 
VALUES(1,qq) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CategoryID = 1
```

then I want the outcome to be

```
1 qq
2 b
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong command.

Use this query instead:

```
REPLACE INTO categories (CategoryID,CategoryName) 
VALUES(1,qq);
```

**Here's why your query does not work**

```
INSERT INTO categories(CategoryID,CategoryName) 
VALUES(1,qq) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CategoryID = 1
```

This code tries to insert 1 into `CategoryID` that doesn't work, because 1 is already in the table.
Next the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause runs.
This sets `CategoryID` to 1.
But is was 1 before, it's 1 after so nothing has changed and you are still trying to insert a duplicate key.

After that MySQL is out of options and gives up.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right statement but in the wrong way.

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO categories(CategoryID,CategoryName)
VALUES(1,"qq") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CategoryID = 1
```

you should write

```
INSERT INTO categories(CategoryID,CategoryName)
VALUES(1,"qq") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CategoryName = VALUES(CategoryName)
```

because after the keyword `UPDATE` you have to put the columns that you want to change, which in your case is CategoryName. `VALUES(CategoryName)` means that the new value is the one that you already stated for the `INSERT` - which is "qq", in the example.

This is the official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This statement is better than `REPLACE INTO` for several reasons. See here, for instance: [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)